# Played 113/201 missions in GTA online. How do I play the other 88 missions?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

In my GTA 5 online stats, I can see I played 113 of 201 missions. I played every contact mission from Lester, Ron, Martin, Gerald, Lamar, Simeon and Trevor.

If I press start and host a game, I can only host missions I completed.

Every mission I request by phone is a mission I played and that since 5 days. So I'm wondering, how do I play the other 88 missions?

Comment: Is your rank above 75?

Comment: my current rank is 81

Comment: I may check in the next day or so. Look at your map, ticked is completed. Races and parachuting may be counted, LTS, deathmatch so on.

Answer (score 1):

Open this menu with;

Pause > Online > Jobs > Play Job > Rockstar Created

---

This brings up a selection of any Adversary Mode, Mission, Race, LTS, etc.

On the sidebar there is an icon of the gamemode (Flag for race, Star for mission) and a green tick will appear if the job has been completed, if not, you'll have to play said mission.